# Не работает команда $PATH

Tags: java, path

Проблема вот в чем:
Набираю команду javac -version
javac 1.8.0_221
( это работает)
Но если набрать $PATH то:
'$PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

P.S Я попробовал решить проблему указать путь в "переменные данные" вот :
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin
Но это не сработало.
А также в PsModulePath добавил %SystemRoot%\system32;
Но это тоже не сработало.

Comment: `%PATH%` пробовали?

Comment: @IZek [клацк сюда](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам надо вывести в консоль содержимое этой переменной? Тогда надо не саму переменную писать, но `echo ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ`. Вроде в разных консолях надо переменную обозначать спец. символами. В вашем случае это будет

`echo $PATH`

или

`echo %PATH%`

Comment: Когда писал echo $PATH , консоль выдала просто : $PATH. Когда же echo %PATH% , то уже сработало и показало путь , вот:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin , я новичок поэтому не понимаю так и должно все работать?

Comment: @IZek, да, так и должно быть. В PATH переменную записываются пути к папкам, содержащим программы, которые где-то кем-то/чем-то могут использоваться. Например, если у вас есть папка Java в PATH, то вы можете из консоли вызывать `java` без указания полного пути до файла `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe`. Ничего более эта переменная не делает.